# What is the best way to determine if the QTextEdit in my QT app is empty or not?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets, textedit

there's a text editing widget in my QT Widget application. My menu item checks to see if the text edit below is empty. Thus, I'm trying to create a function that checks and returns true/false depending on the situation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to do it (illustrated with a function, for clarity):

```
bool IsTextEditEmpty(const QTextEdit * myTextEdit)
{
   return myTextEdit->document()->isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. It was an ideal way to go about it. I checked the length earlier by exporting the TextEdit file to plain text. Using this method is more efficient. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any function QML TextEdit has [length](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#length-prop) property,  simply reading this property and evaluating as bool will return true if TextEdit has non-empty text and false on empty text.

Comment: OP is interested in QtWidgets not QML.

Comment: Thanks, but QT Widgets was the problem here

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question, TextEdit was mentioned instead of QTextEdit along with the qml tag